# How to convert to List<int> to File?

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to store image file to SQLite database using SQLite.

I used this method,

```
 var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: imageSource);
    List<int> bytes = await image.readAsBytes();
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55258035/11065582

**QUESTION 1**
    - what is the type when create table?(CREATE TABLE registerTable(image ?,)
**QUESTION 2**
    - how to convert to again File?

Comment: `ImagePicker.pickImage` returns `Future<File>` so use `File.path` and store the path in your table, not the whole image

Comment: thank you for file.path is working...Because of my application can use online and offine. when application use offline store images to local

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a `List<int>` that represents a list of 8-bit bytes and want to write it to a file, you can simply use [`File.writeAsBytes`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-io/File/writeAsBytes.html). (It's the inverse of [`File.readAsBytes`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-io/File/readAsBytes.html), which you're already using.)

```
await File(desiredDestinationPath).writeAsBytes(bytes);
```

All that said, why do you need to write to a `File`?  If you already have the image data and want to show it, you can create a [`MemoryImage`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/MemoryImage-class.html) (or use [`Image.memory`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html) if you need an `Image` widget).

Comment: I am using above code to write the file but its giving me error: 

Unhandled Exception: type 'List<List<int>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>'

How I can use the above code in my condition when my list is of type  'List<List<int>>' .

Please Help!

Comment: @AlokBanjare That probably deserves its own question, but if you have a `List<List<int>>` that you'd want to write to a single file, you'd have to flatten it into a `List<int>` first (e.g. `File(path).writeAsBytes([for (var list in listOfLists) ...list])`.  If it's very large, it'd be more memory-friendly to use `File(path).open(mode: FileMode.write)` and then call [`RandomAccessFile.writeFrom`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-io/RandomAccessFile/writeFrom.html) on each element.

Comment: nice and easy thanks dude